# In Big Bang Nucleosynthesis (BBN), why aren't anti-protons created and destroyed?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, big-bang, antimatter, nucleosynthesis

I'm working through BBN theory with Dodelson and other papers.  I have a question about the reactions between particles in the $1\space MeV$ range.  We have reactions that produce and annihilate protons and neutrons during this epoch, so where is the treatment for anti-protons and anti-neutrons?  Isn't the universe creating and destroying anti-protons and anti-neutrons during this same time?  Won't the anti-protons and protons react during this epoch to produce photons?  Won't high-energy photons collide and produce protons and anti-protons?

Yes, I know about the hand-waving argument that we're just going to pretend there's some asymmetry between matter and anti-matter and jam in a free parameter which is the baryon-photon ratio at the onset of nucleosynthesis, but that doesn't address the fact that anti-protons should be created under the same conditions as protons.  It appears that the abundance of any given species of particle at a given time depends on accounting for every possible reaction.  I don't understand the justification for leaving out what appears to me to be the most important reaction of the $1\space MeV$ temperature range.

Comment: Without access to the specific references you're working with, this question is difficult to understand. It would help if you included *what* reactions specifically you're talking about, and what the assumed particle content of the universe at that point in time is.

Comment: @ACuriousMind - Dodelson, Scott - **Modern Cosmology** Chapter 3.  The universe consists of protons, electrons, positrons, neutrons and high-energy photons at this point.  I don't see any discussion or consideration of anti-protons or anti-neutrons at this point, though I consider it self-evident that if protons are created in these conditions, then we should be creating anti-protons as well.  The major reactions tracked during this discussion is the proton to neutron ratio and, then, ultimately, Deuterium and $^4He$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anti-protons have a rest-mass energy of 938 MeV. They are not created in reactions at temperatures of just 1 MeV and neither are protons or neutrons.

The protons were created much earlier (at around $10^{-6}$s and $k_BT\sim 1$ GeV, along with anti-protons), but most of them annihilated with anti-protons as the universe cooled, leaving the protons that remain due to the baryon asymmetry, and a huge ($\sim 10^{9}$) excess of photons.

The proton/neutron ratio isn't changing (at $k_BT \sim 1$ MeV) because baryons are being created and destroyed; it changes because weak interactions are able to change neutrons to protons and vice-versa and the rest mass energy difference between a neutron and a proton is only 1.4 MeV.

Comment: If there is no annihilation at temperatures on the order of $1\space MeV$, then what physical process is changing the ratio between protons and neutrons (in equilibrium, that is, I understand that neutrons decay once they fall out of equilibrium)?

Comment: In the absence of this mysterious baryon asymmetry, is there an expectation that an equal number of baryons and photons would exist?  I understand that protons and anti-protons annihilate and produce photons, but is there a baseline to say "this is what the baryon-photon ratio would be without the reaction of protons and anti-protons"?

Comment: @GluonSoup No, the expectation is that all the baryons would annihilate and the universe would be full of photons, since they are not energetic enough to produce massive particles once $T<$ a few hundred MeV.